# Entity Framework doesn't correctly create complex type from MySql stored

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012, MySQL connector 6.9.8 and MySql 5.6.21 with Entity Framework v4.0.30319.

i created a stored as follow:

```
SELECT *
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.id_table1 = table2.idn_table2
where data > DATE_SUB('2014-07-22 17:58:55',INTERVAL 30 minute);
```

It returns all fields of table1 and table2.

Then, i created an edmx Model.
In vs2012, in the Model Browser i added a Function Import of that Stored Procedure, that creates a .cs class (Solution Explorer). But that class is empty (no property created)

```
namespace MyProj
{
 using System;

 public partial class getInstanceList_Result
 {
 }
}
```

During adding Function Import, when a click on the "get columns informations" button of the stored, EDM Type are "NOT SUPPORTED".

How can i fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been a bug for years. They keep releasing newer versions of .Net connector but they don't fix this bug, not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the `MySql` connector (check [the bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69731)). Not sure if there's a way around it other than creating all the needed stuff by hand (or use entities instead of complex types).

The bug is open since 2013 by the way, and not fixed for later versions of EF either.